# Excel How To Measure Distance When Gap In Days

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to measure distance between odometer readings between C7 and C6. The code I'm using will show that distance if there is data in C7 and C6. The problem is my code does not measure odometer distance if my data is in lets say C8 and C6.

How can I correct my code to show distance where there is a gap in data within the C column data? That gap may span a week or more.

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(C9),ISBLANK(C8)),"",C9-C8)
```

Comment: Could you please upload a photo of different examples?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you tagged `VBA`? Or would that rather be `Excel-Formula`

Answer (score 0):

Why not:

```
=MAX($C$7:$C$15)-$C$6
```

The odo reading will only ever increase (unless there is some "clocking" going on...), so find the highest reading and subtract the C6 reading.

Change C15 to be the end of the range in col C you will be working with.

[image]